# как написать автообновление содержимого окна в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

**Делаю кликер, но для того чтобы автокликер 1 клик в секунду работал, нужно чтобы окно обновлялось. Как это сделать?**

```
import time
from tkinter import *

i = 0
o = 1

def clck():
    global i
    i = i + o
    click['text'] = str(i) + '$'

def rst():
    global i
    i = 0
    click['text'] = str(i) + '$'

def oneclick():
    global i
    global o
    if i >= 100:
        i = i - 100
        o = o + 1

def autoclck():
    global i


window = Tk()
window.title("опаопа")
window.geometry('500x300') 

lbl = Label(window, text="Кликер", font=('Impact 50'))
lbl.pack()

click = Button(window, text=str(i) + '$', command=clck, font="16", background="#000", foreground="#fff", padx="40", pady="16")
click.pack()

reset = Button(window, text="Сброс", background="#000", foreground="#fff", padx="20", pady="8", font="16", command=rst)
reset.pack()

buyOneClick = Button(window, text="Купить + 1 клик \n 100$", background="#000", foreground="#fff", padx="20", pady="8", font="16", command=oneclick)
buyOneClick.pack(side=LEFT)

buyAutoClicker = Button(window, text="Купить автокликер 1 клик/с \n 1000$", background="#000", foreground="#fff", padx="20", pady="8", font="16", command=autoclck)
buyAutoClicker.pack(side=RIGHT)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `window.update()`

Comment: window.update() не робит